# Is it possible to add Google Picker to a Discord Button?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, google-picker

I have been trying to create a Discord bot using Discord.js and the Google Picker API. I was wondering if there was a way to click on a button in Discord which would directly open up the Google Picker.

Clicking on this button would open up the Picker:

[image: Clicking on this button would open up the Picker]

Comment: You can redirect to a link with the button style `LINK`.

Comment: @Leau I'm quite new to JS are you familiar with how to go about it

Comment: Do you have the link to redirect to?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons) for Discord Buttons

I leave you an example of how to use the button to which it refers

```
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton } = require('discord.js');

//add your code here, and the example as an embed and response message
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
    .addComponents(
        new MessageButton()
        .setURL('your.url.here')
            .setLabel('Google Picker')
            .setStyle('LINK') )
            message.reply({
                content: 'Google Picker?',
                components: [row] //if you want to add more buttons, it would be like this: components: [row, row1, row2, row...]
            })
```